# Does DynamoDBMapper's query() method only work for primary keys that are composite?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In the documentation for DynamoDBMapper's query() method, it says the following:

> Queries a table or a secondary index. You can query a table or an
> index only if it has a composite primary key (partition key and sort
> key).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Methods.html#DynamoDBMapper.Methods.query

What happens if the table's primary key only has a partition key? Does the read become eventually consistent? Will it error out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states this wrongly and I have submitted feedback to update it. You can use Query for a table which only has a PK with no implications, it should work exactly as you'd expect.